# Include only one block of a different ipynb file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Using `%run file.ipynb` you can run the code of another ipynb file in your current file. However, I'd rather want to run only the first block of code instead of the whole file. That's because in the first block I usually put all self defined functions and in the blocks below I test them and play with them. In the other file I still want to use the fucntions but of course not the testing and playing.